# Why some border is overlapped by the previous cell border?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

The following is the output of the react code:

```css
.borderCell {
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
.shiftCell{
    background-color:#ff99cc;
    min-width:27px;
    text-align: center; 
}
.shiftContent:focus{
    outline: none
}
.shiftContent{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.shiftContent::-moz-selection{
    background: none; 
}
.shiftContent::selection{
    background: none; 
}
.littleSquareDiv {
    background-color: rgb(0, 140, 255);
    top: calc(100% - 3px);
    left: calc(100% - 3px);
    height: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 6px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.littleSquareDiv:hover {
    cursor: crosshair;
}
.selectCellBorderBottom{
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0, 140, 255);
}
.selectCellBorderLeft{
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(0, 140, 255);
}
.selectCellBorderRight{
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(0, 140, 255);
}
.selectCellBorderTop{
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(0, 140, 255);
}
```

```html
    <table class="m-3">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="borderCell shiftContent " contenteditable="true">0,0</td>
          <td class="borderCell shiftContent " contenteditable="true">1,0</td>
          <td class="borderCell shiftContent " contenteditable="true">2,0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="borderCell shiftContent " contenteditable="true">0,1</td>
          <td class="borderCell shiftContent selectCellBorderTop selectCellBorderBottom selectCellBorderRight selectCellBorderLeft" contenteditable="true">1,1</td>
          <td class="borderCell shiftContent " contenteditable="true">2,1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="borderCell shiftContent " contenteditable="true">0,2</td>
          <td class="borderCell shiftContent " contenteditable="true">1,2</td>
          <td class="borderCell shiftContent " contenteditable="true">2,2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

When I place the code to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umcs4v1x/), the central cell 4 border can be shown successfully.
Unfortunately, when the above code is outputted by [react](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-obbahp?file=src%2FshiftCellTest%2FuseShiftCellTest.js,src%2FshiftCellTest%2FShiftCellTest.js,src%2FshiftCellTest%2FShiftCell.js)(please click the central cell) only the right, the bottom border of the central cell can be shown successfully.

Would you tell me why?

The expected result as below:

[image: This is the expected result]

Comment: try using [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) to reproduce your react issue.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the following CSS code (maybe added by bootstrap):

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Try adding the following to your code:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: separate !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you like the see the table like this?

[image]

Comment: {/* <td class="borderCell shiftContent selectCellBorderTop selectCellBorderBottom selectCellBorderRight selectCellBorderLeft" contenteditable="true">1,1</td> */}

<td class="borderCell shiftContent selectCellBorderBottom selectCellBorderRight" contenteditable="true">1,1</td>

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I changed the CSS as below:

```
.borderCell {
   border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
   border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
.borderCell:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

tbody tr:last-child td.borderCell {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

It works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Are you like the see the table like this?

[image: Are you like the see the table like this]

Comment: I don't like it

Comment: give a screenshot what you like.

Comment: Screenshot is uploaded.